# Wordpress permalink without domain name

Tags: wordpress, trim, permalinks

OK it might sound stange but I am facing a good challenge with wordpress. 
when echoing `the_permalink();` and checking the portfolio pages, I am getting a link something like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/?portfolio=test
```

(Where test is the portfolio name).

Is there any option to return the permalink trimmed to `?portfolio=test` keeping out the domain url?
While asking, I think I got the answer already (`trim()`) but I would like to hear your ideas too.

every answer will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the permalink of a post by doing something like so:

```
<?php 
    function my_permalink() {
        echo substr(get_permalink(), strlen(get_option('home')));
    }
?>
```

The get_option method replaces the deprecated get_settings method, and allows you to retrieve named option values from the database:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

The 'home' value passed in to the get_option method will return the site URL.

Comment: I knew there would be a great solution for this! Thanks Matt!

Comment: Fantastic, glad to have helped.

Comment: For anyone who might be having issues with this don't forget to use `get_permalink()` and not `the_permalink()` which will print the full link for you regardless.